# What is the difference between Resource Class and Provider class in JAX-RS/Jersey?

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

In Jersey/JAX-RS I hear the terms "Resource classes" and "Providers". I am not clear on what the difference between these two are. Can someone please provide some proper explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Resource classes](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#jaxrs-resources) are your classes annotated with `@Path` and providers are any other classes that we can extend/implement that allow us to tap into/extend the JAX-RS framework, i.e.

- `ContainerRequestFilter`
- `ContainerResponseFilter`
- `MessageBodyReader`
- `MessageBodyWriter`
- `WriterInterceptor`
- `ReaderInterceptor`
- `ContextResolver`
- `ExceptionMapper`
- `ClientRequestFilter`
- `ClientResponseFilter`

Aside from the client filters, all of these provider classes can be annotated with `@Provider` and automatically register on the server side when scanning is enabled.

You might often hear questions like "What JSON provider are you using?" This refers to the `MessageBodyReader` or `MessageBodyWriter`, which is a type of provider, or more precisely an "Entity Provider", as mentioned in [the docs](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#message-body-workers). This is really the only provider type with its own prefix type. All others are just generalized as being a "Provider".

There may be more provider types, but these are all I can think of off the top of my head right now.

Comment: Thank you Paul.Get a lot Clarity by reading your Post.