# Maven Java Jersey Rest : No provider classes found. (404 error when accessing URL)

Tags: eclipse, maven, windows-7, jersey, tomcat9

I have searched whole StackOverflow network, saw a lot of questions with different solutions, but none help... Please, don't mark the question as duplicate.

Hello, I'm a beginner in java. I'm trying for too many days to create a simple webservice using jersey rest webservices. So I created a class in my project that i called HelloUblu. I have tried this code in another project and it works but in this project I have those issues. I think the main problem is « No provider classes found. »

Thank you very much for your help

I'm working on Eclipse Photon, windows 7, Maven 4, Jersey 
Tomcat 9, JAVASE-1.8 (jre1.8.0_181)

[My path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQgxJ.png)

POM.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.ublu.msm</groupId>
    <artifactId>msm_backend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>msm_server Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>msm_backend</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

WEB.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">
    <display-name>Msm_Backend</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.ublu.msm.msm_backend</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

MY CLASS : HelloUblu.java

```
    package com.ublu.msm.msm_backend.soa.server;

import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.Status;

@Path("helloublu")
public class HelloUblu {
    public HelloUblu() {
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public String getXml() {
        return "<bonjour>Bonjour UBLU</bonjour>";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response getXmlWithParams(@PathParam("id") String id,
            @DefaultValue("all") @HeaderParam("name") String name) {
        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(name);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("<bonjour>Bonjour UBLU de la part de " + name + "</bonjour>").build();
    }

}
```

Logs (INFOS: No provider classes found.)

```
    oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server built:          Sep 4 2018 22:13:41 UTC
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Server number:         9.0.12.0
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Name:               Windows 7
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: OS Version:            6.1
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Architecture:          amd64
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Version:           1.8.0_181-b13
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFOS: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.17] using APR version [1.6.3].
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFOS: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFOS: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018]
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:26 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:27 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:27 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFOS: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 12883 ms
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service [Catalina]
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:38 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration [C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample.xml]
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
AVERTISSEMENT: The path attribute with value [/CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample] in deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample.xml] has been ignored
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample' did not find a matching property.
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:43 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:44 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig init
INFOS: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:44 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFOS: Root resource classes found:
  class com.crunchify.restjersey.HelloUblu
  class com.crunchify.restjersey.CtoFService
  class com.crunchify.restjersey.FtoCService
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:44 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFOS: No provider classes found.
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:44 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFOS: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.4 05/24/2017 03:46 PM'
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\CrunchifyRESTJerseyExample.xml] has finished in [6 750] ms
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Déploiement du descripteur de configuration [C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\msm_backend.xml]
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
AVERTISSEMENT: The path attribute with value [/msm_backend] in deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\msm_backend.xml] has been ignored
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:45 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:msm_backend' did not find a matching property.
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:52 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFOS: Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\msm_backend.xml] has finished in [7 116] ms
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
oct. 12, 2018 10:38:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 25008 ms
```

MAVEN BUILD CLEAN INSTALL

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< msm_backend:msm_backend >-----------------------
[INFO] Building msm_backend 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ msm_backend ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\msm_backend\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ msm_backend ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ msm_backend ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 61 source files to C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\msm_backend\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Users/Wilfried/workspace2/msm_backend/msm_backend/src/main/java/com/ublu/msm/msm_backend/StructureManager.java: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Users/Wilfried/workspace2/msm_backend/msm_backend/src/main/java/com/ublu/msm/msm_backend/StructureManager.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ msm_backend ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ msm_backend ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ msm_backend ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.1:war (default-war) @ msm_backend ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [msm_backend] in [C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\msm_backend\target\msm_backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\msm_backend\WebContent]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1113 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\msm_backend\target\msm_backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ msm_backend ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\msm_backend\target\msm_backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\Users\Wilfried\.m2\repository\msm_backend\msm_backend\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\msm_backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Wilfried\workspace2\msm_backend\pom.xml to C:\Users\Wilfried\.m2\repository\msm_backend\msm_backend\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\msm_backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.234 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-12T23:17:55+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: _"No provider classes found"_ - That's just an INFO message. No need to worry about it. Also it says that it found three resource classes HelloUblu, CtoFService, FtoCService. So those are registered. Make sure you're using the right URL if you are getting a 404. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52728047/2587435)

Comment: Hello Paul thanks for your answer ! But those ressource classes are for another project... It doesn't load the good ones